# WPF: Scale a shape and its Bounding Box to fit another Canvas - without affecting Stroke Thickness

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, scaling

I have some shapes described in XAML, mostly curved lines. Some of them have padding around the edges, achieved by placing them in a `Canvas` larger than the shape. This `Canvas` acts as a bounding box.

For example, this shape appears like this in Designer. The shape is the curved line. The outer square is the bounding `Canvas`, indicated by red arrows.

```
<Canvas Height="160"
        Width="160"
        Background="Red">
  <Path Stroke="#000000"
        Data="M27.9,108 c0,0 25,-63 48.5,-51.5 s34.5,64.5 68.5,37">
  </Path>
</Canvas>
```

[image]

Now I need to scale the `Canvas` and its shape to dynamically fit a larger `Canvas`, while maintaining the shape's `Geometry` relative to its bounding `Canvas`, and also while maintaining the `Stroke.Thickness`.

This is how the shape appears without scaling (bounding `Canvas` is red, `Canvas`I need to scale to is yellow):

[image]

This how it needs to look after scaling, but without changing the `Stroke.Thickness`. Here I'm using a `ViewBox`:

[image]

Is there a solution to this problem that I am overlooking?

I suspect the only solution involves setting the shape's `Path.Stretch` to `Fill`, changing its `Height` and `Width`, and then applying a `Margin` to the bounding `Canvas` to replicate the padding, which sounds quite horrible.

Comment: Path.Data is a Geometry, which has a Transform property.

Comment: Don't use `Canvas` instead of `Path.Margin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the `Path.Stretch` property to `Fill` and the geometry will automatically scale to the size of the shape. Unfortunately, when the geometry is stretched, it is also "trimmed" to a minimal bounding box, so you'll loose the margins around the geometry, but you can always set `Path.Margin` to desired values. Also, you should drop the wrapping `Canvas` altogether.

However, judging by the image with desired effect you also want the margin to scale together with the geometry itself. In this case setting `Path.Margin` won't cut the mustard - the margins will remain "constant". Fortunately, there's a simple trick that will solve this problem - all you need to do is to incorporate the margins in the geometry itself. To do that, you simply need to add two "empty" moves to the geometry, which would define two opposite points of the desired bounding box. In your case, if you want the shape to be nominally of size 160x160, and scale automatically to fit the available space, all you need is this:

```
<Path Stroke="#000000"
      Data="M0,0 M160,160 M27.9,108 c0,0 25,-63 48.5,-51.5 s34.5,64.5 68.5,37"
      Stretch="Fill" />
```

`Path` does not have a `Background` property though, so you might want to wrap it with a `Border` after all.

Comment: Adding the extra Move commands worked a treat. Thank you! I had a feeling there would be a somewhat unintuitive but simple solution lurking somewhere.